# Conerstone SVN edit files in the program

Tags: macos, svn, tortoisesvn, cornerstone

I´m new to SVN, but I have been using tortoiseSVN for Windows for 2 weeks.
Now I have to use Cornerstone SVN for Mac OS X. 
My question:
Is it possible to edit a file (for example txt files) inside Cornerstone or do I have to copy the file everytime I want to edit it to my Mac and then upload it?
I liked the function in tortoise, that you only work on your explorer (finder on Mac) without a own GUI-software and that you could upload the edited files without making a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are familiar with the basics of SVN. As long as you edit files in the working copy of you repository, you can use either terminal or SVN client like Cornerstone to commit your changes.

You mentioned in windows you only work on your explorer, but I would say that is not the case. When you try to edit files, the system usually need to launch certain apps to do the job, e.g. text editor or code editor, etc. So does in Mac OS X.